# Tricky T-SQL Query. Concatenate multiple values from a column between master/child tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, concatenation, xquery, sql-server-group-concat

I have three tables as follows:

MasterTable

```
+----------+-------------+
| MasterId | MasterName  |
+----------+-------------+
| 1        | Master 1    |
| 2        | Master 2    |
| 3        | Master 3    |
| 4        | Master 4    |
+----------+-------------+
```

ChildrenTable

```
+----------+-------------+
| ChildId | ChildName    |
+----------+-------------+
| 1        | Child 1     |
| 2        | Child 2     |
| 3        | Child 3     |
| 4        | Child 4     |
+----------+-------------+
```

LinkTable

```
+----------+-----------------------+
| Id       | MasterId    | ChldId  |
+----------+-----------------------+
| 1        |  1          | 1       | 
| 2        |  2          | 1       | 
| 3        |  3          | 2       | 
| 4        |  4          | 3       | 
+----------+-----------------------+
```

One child can be linked with multiple masters and LinkTable contains this detail. I want a query to select the following:

```
1, 'Child 1', 'Master 1, Master 2', '1,2'
2, 'Child 2', 'Master 2', '2'
3, 'Child 3', 'Master 3', '3'
```

Is it possible to do without loops or calling additional function, using `COALESCE`, `STUFF`, recursive `CTE` etc?

Comment: Why your `LinkTable` table contains two duplicate `MasterId` column?

Comment: @S.Serpooshan probably meant to be Id for this table. Don't even remember this now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To concatenate strings you can use this method: [How to concatenate all strings from a certain column for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579440/how-to-concatenate-all-strings-from-a-certain-column-for-each-group/6579570#6579570)

Test data:

```
declare @masterTable table(MasterId int identity, MasterName varchar(max))
insert @masterTable (MasterName) values('m1'), ('m2'), ('m3'), ('m4')

declare @childrenTable table(ChildId int identity, ChildName varchar(max))
insert @childrenTable (ChildName) values('c1'), ('c2'), ('c3'), ('c4')

declare @LinkTable table(MasterId1 int, MasterId2 int, ChildId int)
insert @LinkTable values(1,1,1), (2,2,1), (3,3,2), (4,4,3)
```

Query:

```
select t.*
from
(
    select c.ChildId, c.ChildName

        , STUFF((
            select ', ' + m.MasterName
            from
            (
                select l.MasterId1
                from @LinkTable l
                where l.ChildId = c.ChildId

                union

                select l.MasterId2
                from @LinkTable l
                where l.ChildId = c.ChildId
            )t
            join @masterTable m on m.MasterId = t.MasterId1
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') [names]

        , STUFF((
            select ', ' + cast(t.MasterId1 as varchar(max))
            from
            (
                select l.MasterId1
                from @LinkTable l
                where l.ChildId = c.ChildId

                union

                select l.MasterId2
                from @LinkTable l
                where l.ChildId = c.ChildId
            )t
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') [ids]
    from @childrenTable c
)t
where t.ids is not null
```

---

Output:

```
----------- --- -------- ------
1           c1  m1, m2   1, 2
2           c2  m3       3
3           c3  m4       4
```

Answer (score 1):

Though @polishchuk's soluition works, I had my own version below:

```
SELECT  ChildId, ChildName, ISNULL(mastDetail.MasterIds,'')MasterIds, 
        ISNULL(mastDetail.MasterNames, '') MasterNames
FROM    ChildrenTable sub
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
    STUFF( 
            (SELECT  ',' + mast.MasterName
             FROM    MasterTable mast
             INNER JOIN LinkTable link ON (mast.MasterId = link.MasterId AND 
                   link.ChildId = child.ChildId)
             FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1,1,''
        ) AS MasterNames,
    STUFF( 
            (SELECT  ',' + CAST(mast.MasterId AS VARCHAR)
             FROM    MasterTable mast
             INNER JOIN LinkTable link ON (mast.MasterId = link.MasterId AND 
             link.ChildId = child.ChildId)
             FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1,1,''
        ) AS MasterIds
) AS mastDetail
```