# How to concatenate result column values to a single row?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to concatenate the result values into a single row?

I created two tables like this.

first table

```
clientid name
1        test1
2        test2
3        test3
```

second table

```
id   clientid
3    1
3    2
3    3
```

my requirement getting

```
result
3  test1,test2,test3
```

My SP....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_test]-- 3
    @ID INT
AS  
BEGIN
    SELECT CO.id,AR.name FROM dbo.test1 AR
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.test2 CO On AR.clientid=CO.clientid
    WHERE CO.id=@ID
END
```

Then I am getting result as

```
id  name
3   test1
3   test2
3   test3
```

Please modify my sp to get the below format output

```
id  name
3   test1,test2,test3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate all strings from a certain column for each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579440/how-to-concatenate-all-strings-from-a-certain-column-for-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, names = STUFF((
    SELECT N',' + name FROM dbo.test2
    WHERE clientid = x.clientid 
    FOR XML PATH(''), 
    TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, N'')
FROM dbo.test1 AS x
WHERE id = @ID
GROUP BY id;
```