# Concatenate column values as single value SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table with a column:

```
|-------------|
| ColumnName  |
|-------------|
| Value One   |
| Value Two   |
| Value Three |
| Value Four  |
| Value Five  |
|-------------|
```

I will declare a variable,

```
DECLARE @ColumnNameList VARCHAR(MAX)
```

and I should find the below value in my variable

```
'Value One,Value Two,Value Three,Value Four,Value Five'
```

Can anyone help me out in doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to concatenate all strings from a certain column for each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579440/how-to-concatenate-all-strings-from-a-certain-column-for-each-group)

Comment: Use GROUP_CONCAT() Method

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT @ColumnNameList = STUFF 
(
    SELECT ',' + ColumnName  
    FROM TableName
    ORDER BY ColumnName  
    FOR XML PATH('root')
), 1, 1, ''
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @ColumnNameList = coalesce(@ColumnNameList + ',' + ColumnName, ColumnName) 
FROM <table>
SELECT @ColumnNameList
```

Answer (score -1):

Data in dbo.columnnames is:
columnnames
Value One
Value Two
Value Three
Value Four
Value Five

CODE:

```
declare @lv_table table( column_values varchar(100))

declare @product_v varchar(max)

insert into @lv_table

select * from dbo.columnnames


select ''''+
    Stuff(
        (
    SELECT  ',' + column_values 
    FROM  @lv_table
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '') +''''
```

output:

> 'Value One,Value Two,Value Three,Value Four,Value Five'